# XML error 'not well formed'

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i'm having a php file which returns an xml file and I'm getting "Not well formed" error because of the sentence: 
`$name_sql= "SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE product_id = ".$id."";`

The php file I initialised with:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');

include('config.php');

echo'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

How can I rewrite that sentence? Thanks

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');

include('config.php');

error_reporting(E_ALL);


function getName($id) {

  $name_sql= "SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE product_id = ".$id."";

  $name_query = mysql_query($name_sql) or die('Eroare nume: '.mysql_error());
  $nume = mysql_fetch_array($name_query);
  return $nume;
}


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo '<test>';

$var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product order by product_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($var1 = mysql_fetch_array($var)) {
  $nume = getName($var1['product_id']);

  echo '<column><line>'.$nume['name'].'</line></column>';
}


echo '</test>';
```

---

`<?php`

`$_CONFIG['db_host'] = 'xyz';` 
`$_CONFIG['db_user'] = 'xyz';`
`$_CONFIG['db_pass'] = 'xyz';`
`$_CONFIG['db_name'] = 'xyz';`

`$_CONFIG['site_URL'] = 'http://xyz.ro';`

`$lnk = mysql_connect($_CONFIG['db_host'], $_CONFIG['db_user'], $_CONFIG['db_pass']) or die (mysql_error());`
`mysql_select_db($_CONFIG['db_name'], $lnk) or die (mysql_error());`

`?>`

Comment: what does the XML look like?  Does the include file output any text that could mess with the XML data.  Are you saying that `$name_sql = "Select....` is in the final XML document?

Comment: To little information, the query & broken output is probably further on. Show us the non-well-formed stuff, but in general: prefer an xml library to make xml rather then build your own. Like `simplexml` or `DOM`.

Comment: The config.php file sets the connection to database. That code is not the final file. In that code if a remove $id, the XML is generated without errors, only that I need that variable to make my query from database. I hope I explained it right.

Comment: Please post the resulting xml file!

Comment: Error XML: not well formed
Adress: http://xyz.ro/feed/test2.php
Line number 1, column 74664

Comment: But after that error, my xml file is generated correctly. So all I need is to make that error dissapear.

Comment: I will try to put the entire code. Sorry I'm new on this site.

Comment: Try to use `htmlspecialchars($nume['name'])`, probably it contains a `<` / `>` or `&` at some point. On a side note: you _may_ want to add a newline in there after each `<column/>`, it makes it a bit more readable & debuggable.

Comment: It's not containing because after the error, a line below the error, the xml is generated corrected. The problem is that I can't get rid of the error.

Comment: Please output the resultant XML. That will help determine what the problem is.

Comment: I can't because the information on that file is confidential. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your XML must be: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but your `include('config.php')` might be outputting something before it.

Try something like this:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
include('config.php');

function getName($id) {

  $name_sql= "SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE product_id = ".$id."";

  $name_query = mysql_query($name_sql) or die('Eroare nume: '.mysql_error());
  $nume = mysql_fetch_array($name_query);
  return $nume;
}
echo '<test>';

$var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product order by product_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($var1 = mysql_fetch_array($var)) {
  $nume = getName($var1['product_id']);

  echo '<column><line>'.$nume['name'].'</line></column>';
}
echo '</test>';
```

Comment: What do you mean that my configuration file might be outputting something before it?

Comment: If a remove $id from code... my xml is generated, but if I remove $id, the query from database is not working. So that is why I think that the error comes from that line..

Comment: what's the contents of your config.php file?

Comment: I placed it in the main post

Comment: Ok, so it's not the config.php which is the problem. Try changing  error_reporting(E_ALL) to error_reporting(E_NONE). error_reporting(E_ALL) might produce some notices or warnings which will be outputed before <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I tried with error_reporting(0) and error_reporting(E_NONE)

Comment: Can you also post the resulting XML like it was suggested by others?

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 74649: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: media print { #main-iframe-wrapper .TOOLBAR_IFRAME { width: 0 !important; } html { margin-top: 0 !important; } }

Comment: This is the error that appears on one browser, on another is only appering Not well formed